# In Rails 3, how to validate string matches exactly only several strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

I'm creating a model in Rails 3 as follows:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :bar

  type_regex = /(dog)|(cat)|(bird)/

  validates :bar,  :presence => true,
                   :format => { :with => type_regex }
end
```

I need the type to match either dog, cat or bird exactly.  In the above class, however, type_regex will match doggy, cathrine, etc.

How do I make the validation match those strings exactly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add anchors to the regex. Specifically you need to add `\A` to the beginning and `\Z` to the end of the regex (`\A` and `\Z` meaning beginning- and end-of-string respectively).

Be careful with precedence though: due to the low precedence of `|` you'll either have to put a non-capturing group around the alternation or anchor each of the words separately. I.e. you have to do `/\A(?:(dog)|(cat)|(bird))\Z/`. Doing `/\A(dog)|(cat)|(bird)\Z/` will not work because that way the `\A` will only apply to `dog` and the `\Z` only to `bird`.

The same is true if you use `^` and `$` instead of `\A` and `\Z`. On that subject let me explain the difference between those: `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a line, not the string. So the string "dog\ngy" would still match the regex `/^dog$/`, but not the regex `/\Adog\Z/`.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Follow up question to this.  Is my solution the "proper" way to handle such check or is there a better way?

Comment: @Misha: Actually, no. If your pattern is just an alternation of plain strings (i.e. no special regex operations), you should just use `:inclusion => %w(dog cat bird)` instead of a regex.

Answer (score 0):

add $ at the end. For example:

```
  type_regex = /[(dog)|(cat)|(bird)]$/
```

(you might need to escape the $). And to validate the start of string use ^

```
  type_regex = /^[(dog)|(cat)|(bird)]/
```

so this is what you want... I think :)

```
  type_regex = /^[(dog)|(cat)|(bird)]$/
```

Comment: The regex you've shown matches dog at the beginning of the line, bird at the end of the line or cat anywhere in the string. I.e. the strings "doggy", "flying bird" and "lolcat madness" all match your regex. Also note that `^` and `$` mean the beginning and end of the line, not the string.

Comment: upz, well spotted. I'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

The regex you need is:

```
 type_regex = /(^dog$)|(^cat$)|(^bird$)/
```

The other suggestion by Augusto's will still match 'catherine', 'doggie'.

Comment: And your suggestion will still match `"dog\ngie"` and `"cat\nherine"`.